Issues Receiving API Responses in APK Build of Expo React Native App
I'm experiencing a problem with my Expo React Native app. When I run the app and scan the Expo QR code, everything works fine, and I receive the expected API responses. However, after creating an APK build of my app, I am not getting any responses from the API. My APIs are deployed on AWS EC2. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Are your API endpoints using https or http ? If they are http you should set the android:usesCleartextTraffic="true". You can find more info herehttps://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/12539935

A lot of things can result to this particular issue, but the few things you should look into is; API Gateway, App Configuration, Network Configuration, Base URL
